# Query by object's child collection item property on mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am storing a collection of the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ffdb0c70a6560df428aaa3"),
    "name" : "Contact Information",
    "description" : "Basic contact information about myself",
    "questions" : [ 
        {
            "caption" : "First Name",
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : "Last Name",
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : "Email",
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : "Date of bith (mm/dd/yyyy)",
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : "Street Address",
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : "Address Line 2",
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : "State",
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : null,
            "value" : null
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : "Postal Code",
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "caption" : "Country",
            "value" : ""
        }
    ]
```

I need to query based on the parent property "name" or by questions collection and property "caption"

So I have constructed the following query:

```
var result =(from Query in this.CoreService.QuestionCategoriesCollection().AsQueryable()
                            from Questions in Query.questions
                            where Questions.caption.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
                            select Query).ToList();
```

However, when the query runs I receive the following exception:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.NotSupportedException An exception
>   of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll
>   but was not handled in user code: '$project or $group does not support
>   {document}.'    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.AggregateLanguageTranslator.TranslateValue(Expression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.AggregateLanguageTranslator.TranslateMapping(ProjectionMapping
>   mapping)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateProjectValue(Expression
>   selector)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateSelectMany(SelectManyExpression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateWhere(WhereExpression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateSelect(SelectExpression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslatePipeline(PipelineExpression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry,
>   ExpressionTranslationOptions translationOptions)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.GetExecutionModel(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToList[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1
>   source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   projectname.Services.Questions.GetQuestions(String filter) in
>   c:\developerment\project\project\Service\Questions.cs:line 24    at
>   projectnameAPI.Controllers.QuestionsController.Get(String filter) in
>   c:\developerment\project\project\Controllers\QuestionsController.cs:line
>   31    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()

I don't know what other way to write the query using linq.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/linq/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting my query to this.

```
    var result =this.CoreService.QuestionCategoriesCollection().Find(c=>c.name.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
    || c.questions.Any(q=>q.caption.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())));
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner - but more raw - way.
Given the following collection schema example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Get the parent by child id:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    "Children.Id" : "childId"
}
var data = this.ParentCollection().Find(new MongoDB.Driver.CommandDocument(dictionary));
```